# How to group arrays alphabetically with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an array that has several other arrays inside it. All data is already sorted alphabetically.

What I would like to know is how can I group alphabetically?

Just like in the example image below:

[image]

Here's my project I put into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-leftpad-jnib1s?file=/src/index.js)

```js
import "./styles.css";

import { data } from "./data";

export default function App() {
  console.log("data: ", data);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          {item.map((item2, index2) => (
            <div key={index2}>
              <span>{item2.title}</span>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help!!!

Comment: Looks like your `data` in `data.js` is an array of 26 arrays, but not grouped by alpha-numeric characters. I'd start with flattening them into a single array, and `map` or/and `filter` by the first character of `title` value of each object. Will post an answer shortly unless you resolve it sooner.

Comment: Hey Bumhan, If you can post it I would really appreciate it, Because I don't know how to solve this

Comment: Please see the answer below and Code Sandbox link in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR. See the [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-snowflake-liybo6?file=/src/App.js) I cloned and edited from yours.**

In summary, I did something like below:

```js
import "./styles.css";

import { data } from "./data";

export default function App() {
  // Flatten `data` array
  const merged = [];
  data.map((arr) => arr.map((item) => merged.push(item)));

  // Reduce `merged` array by initial character of `title`
  const mapped = merged.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const letter = item.title[0].toLowerCase();
    if (!acc[letter]) {
      acc[letter] = [];
    }
    acc[letter].push(item);
    return acc;
  }, {});

  const letters = Object.keys(mapped);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Grouped by the first initial</h1>
      {letters.map((letter, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <h2>{letter}</h2>
          {mapped[letter].map((item, j) => (
            <div key={j}>{item.title}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

1. Flatten `data` array into `merged` variable.
2. Reduce the `merged` into a dictionary-like object (by each first initial) into `mapped` variable.
3. Then render by `map`ping the `merged` array.

See it in action in the [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-snowflake-liybo6?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Add a function to get rid of the duplicates...

// uniques in `data` array
  let _data = Object.values(
    data.reduce( (c, e) => {
      if (!c[e.id]) c[e.id] = e;
      return c;
    }, {})
  );
  
  // Flatten `data` array
  const merged = [];
  _data.map((arr) => arr.map((item) => merged.push(item)));

Comment: Thank you very much Bumhan, that's work perfectly for me!!!

Comment: Thanks @GuiLeFlea for the great suggestion. The way it’s written is rather bare bone, and the code doesn’t distinguish/categorize numerical and/or special characters. To make it more refined and complete, you might consider 1) de-duplicating data items, 2) checking for numerals and special characters, and 3) excluding the articles `a` or `the`, etc.